# tracking documents without NSURLDocumentIdentifierKey

Tags: ios, nsurl

Apple's ShapeEdit example has a thumbnail cache which is keyed using NSURLDocumentIdentifierKey. See

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ShapeEdit/Introduction/Intro.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ShapeEdit/Listings/ShapeEdit_DocumentBrowser_ThumbnailCache_swift.html

This key is only present if the documents are in iCloud. What sort of key should be used for caching the thumbnails on local documents?